# Combine for and if statements

Tags: php

I've been researching if this is possible, but I've drawn a blank, I'm wondering if it's possible to optimize these for and if statements together? cheers.

Edit (**Updated #2**) : Their is an issue with the code not looping through the pages.

```
<?php
// calculate total number of pages
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $records_per_page);

// range of links to show
$range = 2;

// display links to 'range of pages' around 'current page'
$initial_num = $page - $range;
$condition_limit_num = ($page + $range)  + 1;
?>

    <ul class="pagination margin-zero">
<?php if ($page>1) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo $page_url; ?>page=1' title='Go to the first page.'>First Page</a>
        </li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
for ($x = min($initial_num, 0); $x <= max($condition_limit_num-1, $total_pages); $x++) :
    if ($x == $page) :
        ?>
        <li class='active'>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $x; ?> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo $page_url; ?>page=<?php echo $x; ?>'><?php echo $x; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
    endif;
endfor;
?>

<?php
if ($page<$total_pages) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo $page_url; ?>page=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>' title='Last page is <?php echo $total_pages; ?>'>
                Last Page
            </a>
        </li>
<?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @JonStirling how could it be done please? cheers.

Comment: @B001ᛦthe above code works, I'm just wondering how to go about optimizing it, cheers.

Comment: @HaveaLaugh But that's not what you asked...

Comment: @JonStirling sorry about that, my mistake, that's what I was meant to ask, i guess my wording was incorrect, I'll learn from that mistake, cheers.

Comment: @JonStirling I've edited my question, cheers.

Comment: You might want to post this question somewhere else (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow). StackOverflow is not really about this type of question :).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can combine them if you think about the maximum and minimum value that $x is allowed to get assigned.

The outer for loop would require $x to be contained in the interval [0; $condition_limit_num)

If you look only at the for and the first if you could decide that the minimum has to be larger than zero or initial_num, so you could for example use the minimum of initial_num and zero. The limit would work the same way using the maximum of condition_limit_num-1 and total_pages as uppermost reachable value, i.e. the interval [min($x, 0); max($condition_limit_num-1;$total_pages)].

But if you take into account the innermost if you require $x to have a specific value ($page). That means that this if is only "true" whenever $page is contained in the intervall [min($x, 0); max($condition_limit_num-1;$total_pages)] - you can reduce that check to a single if.

**Update after question update:**

Since the innermost if also has an else path the loop cannot be reduced to a single if:

```
<?php
for ($x = max($initial_num, 0); $x <= min($condition_limit_num-1, $total_pages); $x++)) :
    if($x == $page) :
        ?>
        <li class='active'>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $x; ?> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <?php else : ?>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo $page_url; ?>page=<?php echo $x; ?>'><?php echo $x; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
    endif;
endfor;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it's much appreciated, if possible could you print out the full statement, as I'm only partially understanding your reply, thanks.

Comment: You just have to check each of the boundaries and the equality separately and combine the conditions - for example you could check `if(($x >= min($initial_num, 0)) && ($x <= max($condition_limit_num-1, $total_pages)) && ($x == $page))`.

Comment: thanks very much, I'm beginning to understand it, only small issue is it doesn't seem to be looping through the pages, I've edited the first page to include the full code, sorry I didn't include the full code before.

Comment: It would be interesting how the (working) code looked with your original implementation because you had the last if nested inside the for which selected only a single page - that code should also not have looped over more than one page.

Comment: As i understand your code - did you really have that if($x == $page) inside your for loop? If not then you'd have to use something like `for($x >= min($initial_num, 0); $x <= max($condition_limit_num-1, $total_pages); $x++)` and not filter with $x == $page which doesn't make sense to me when I'm now reading your updated code.

Comment: i've added the original code that i was using before

Comment: i've updated the post with the code you mentioned above adding the for statement, but it seems to break the script with no errors

Comment: Ah ok now i understand your inner 'if'. I've made a typo in my previous comment. It should start with `for($x = min(...` and not with `for($x >= ...`. You can also reduce the `if` inside the for back to if($x == $page) because the other conditions are met by the outer for loop. The script now breaks because $x is not assigned in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's much appreciated, it's almost perfect, I've updated the first post, the pagination currently displays "    -1    0    1 (current)    2    3    Last Page", it's breaking the loop out of the page limit.

Comment: This can only be the case when `$initial_num` is negative. In case you implement pagination I guess that this should never be the case and that you want to use that as a "base" index so you could use `max($initial_num, 0)` or even `max($initial_num, 1)`if there is no page 0 for the lower bound. In case on the upper bound if `$total_pages` is an absolut upper bound and $condition_limit_num is an selected range inside then you should change that to `min($condition_limit_num-1, $total_pages)`. This always chooses the narrower interval.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it, I do have one more question, the <?php else : ?> loop causes 4 whitespaces at the end of it in the HTML, I know it's not a big deal but by any chance is their a way to remove them easily? thank you very much!

Comment: Whitespace should be insignifcant in HTML anyways but if I guess correctly what you mean you could try to remove the indention of <?php (if you've indented like in the code snipped posted in your question).

Comment: thanks, that sorted it, thanks again for all your help, it's much appreciated :)